# UDEV-How to get value of a child device attributes

Tags: linux, serial-port, udev

I am writting an udev rule to set name of two serial ports. I want to use the value of the attribute **bInterfaceNumber** in the symlink.

My rules is:

> SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6010", SYMLINK+="toto%s{bInterfaceNumber}"

The rule matched the device but value of the attribute is never found.

Here is the hierarchical view of one device:

```
console@host:udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="6010"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rule I made to create an alias for a dual port FTDI chip:

```
# Internal serial ports
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{interface}=="Dual RS232", SYMLINK+="sertest%s{bInterfaceNumber}"
```

According to this [post](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg54230.html), the attributes must be matching on one level. That's why `idVendor` and `idProduct` won't work with `bInterfaceNumber`. Below, you can see that `interface` and `bInterfaceNumber` belong to the same level:

```
looking at parent device '/devices/platform/omap/musb-ti81xx/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0':
KERNELS=="1-1.2:1.0"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="ff"
ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff"
ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
ATTRS{interface}=="Dual RS232"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I done the same rule. I would have liked to use idvendor to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use environmental variables like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017203/udev-rule-with-few-parent-device-attributes/27222804#27222804).

In your case it will be something like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", DRIVER=="ftdi_sio", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6010" ENV{MY_DEV}="yes"

ENV{MY_DEV}="yes", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", SYMLINK+="toto%s{bInterfaceNumber}"
```

Comment: That did not quite work, but with some inspiration from /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules:
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}="$attr{bInterfaceNumber}"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6011", SYMLINK+="tty%s{serial}_$env{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}"