# udev rule for symlinking usb device

Tags: linux, usb, gsm, udev

I'm working on a mobile application that uses dedicated netbooks as hardware platform, the software runs on arch linux. In order to enable mobile internet access, I want to integrate a gsm modem in the setup, the modem is connected via usb. As my software expects a fixed device name of the modem, I'm trying to use a custom udev-rule to create a symlink to the modem device as it's plugged in. My current udev rules looks like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="140c", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="gsm"
```

The problem is, that when I plug in the modem, two devices seem to be created, as can be seen using `dmesg`:

```
[ 3955.586471] option 1-1:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 3955.587286] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 3955.587946] option 1-1:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 3955.588637] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
```

Talking to the modem only seems to work on the `ttyUSB2`. However, the symlink created by udev always seems to point to `ttyUSB1`, thus, it cannot be used to communicate with the modem. Can anyone explain this behaviour and tell my how I can change it?

I already tried to use udevadm info to find distinguishable attributes, in order to make the rule more spedific. The devices only seem to differ in their `bInterfaceNumber`, but I could not successfully include that attribut in the udev rule.

Comment: It is probably a modem port and a diagnostics port, and you need the modem port. This is normal for plug-in modems - some (Qualcomm based) also have a 3rd port for GPS data, for example. Can't help you with how to change to the modem port on linux, sorry :-( .

Comment: Please take a look at [ModemManager](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ModemManager/). This software will take care about modem independent from its manufacturer and port names and give you a standard device to communicate with via [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/). It can also communicate with modems via [QMI](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libqmi) and [MBIM](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libmbim/).

Comment: As for **udev** see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273418/udev-how-to-get-value-of-a-child-device-attributes