# udev rule with few parent device attributes

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, udev

I need complex and universal `udev` rule to determine USB-device plugged in certain port of the any USB hub. so, i have to combine parent attributes of different layers of the device tree...

I have this:

```
$udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk

  looking at device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.4:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

            . . .

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4':
    KERNELS=="1-1.2.4"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
            ...

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2':
    KERNELS=="1-1.2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.2"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0835"
            ...
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="8500"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0 Hub"

            . . .
```

Then i constructed udev rule something like this to identify certain port of certain USB hub:

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", KERNELS=="1-1.2.4", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0835", ATTRS{idProduct}=="8500", SYMLINK+="port1"
```

But it's not working when i try to use attributes from different parent layers.

I know that udev supports additional attributes only from one particular parent device. But I really need to get the rule that combines attributes from 2 parent nodes of my device

Could anybody suggest the solution? Is there any trick to get it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After many of unsuccessful experiences, i found the solution!

The key feature of it is setting the environment variable:

1. On plugging event, we looking the `vendor:id` pair and remember it in environment variable.
2. On the same event, we compare the saved variable and usb-device tree nodes IDs to assign exact names of ports of certain usb-hub.

This document helped me http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="05e3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0610", ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}="05e3:0610"
KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0835", ATTRS{idProduct}=="8500", ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}="0835:8500"
#
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="0835:8500", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.[2-3].4:1.0", SYMLINK+="port1"
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="0835:8500", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.[2-3].3:1.0", SYMLINK+="port2"
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="0835:8500", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.[2-3].2:1.0", SYMLINK+="port3"
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="0835:8500", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.[2-3].5.5:1.0", SYMLINK+="port4"
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="0835:8500", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.[2-3].5.2:1.0", SYMLINK+="port5"
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="0835:8500", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.[2-3].5.3:1.0", SYMLINK+="port6"
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="0835:8500", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.[2-3].5.4:1.0", SYMLINK+="port7"
#
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="05e3:0610", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.[2-3].1.1:1.0" SYMLINK+="port1"
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="05e3:0610", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.[2-3].2:1.0", SYMLINK+="port2"
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="05e3:0610", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.[2-3].1.2:1.0", SYMLINK+="port3"
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="05e3:0610", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.[2-3].3:1.0", SYMLINK+="port4"
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="05e3:0610", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.[2-3].1.3:1.0", SYMLINK+="port5"
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="05e3:0610", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.[2-3].4:1.0", SYMLINK+="port6"
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="05e3:0610", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.[2-3].1.4:1.0", SYMLINK+="port7"
```

Perhaps, it will be useful for someone.

Comment: Bravo. Excellent work.  The hoops we have to jump through eh?

Answer (score 0):

worked percect for me on my openhabian-system. I have two identical usb/modbus-adapters and now I can give them different symlinks:
added these lines in my /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules:

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7523", ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}="1a86:7523"
#
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="1a86:7523", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*",SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.3:1.0", SYMLINK+="tty4800"
ENV{USB_HUB_TYPE}=="1a86:7523", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*",SUBSYSTEM=="tty", KERNELS=="1-1.2:1.0", SYMLINK+="tty9600"
```